# I can't upgrade my plan in firebase to blaze plan

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to upgrade my plan to blaze, since I want to implement more features to my website for email sending purposes.

But it keeps giving me this error: [image]

Already contacted customer service, but they're not giving me an accurate response or solution.

Any one knows what this might be?

Comment: *firebaser here* "they're not giving me an accurate response or solution" What does this mean? Can you elaborate, or share a case number so I can have a look?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the error message, you have already reached the quota limit of your billing account. Because of this, you will not be able to upgrade to Blaze plan, as well as request for quota increase as you are still in a  (Free) Spark plan.

You have 2 options:

- Delete atleast one project linked to your billing account.
- Link your project to a different billing account.

Additionally, if you choose to delete a project associated to your billing account please keep in mind that it will take 30 days for a project to be completely delete as mentioned in this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/creating-managing-projects#shutting_down_projects).